# Javascript duplicate key store value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

I have a firebase collections which i have succeeded into getting the values as follows

```
One Data set
{
    
    "region": [
        "region"
    ],
   
    "gender": [
        "female"
    ],
 
}
Another Data set
{

    
    "region": [
        "region"
    ],
   
    "gender": [
        "female"
    ],
 
}
```

What I have tried too far is mapping only

```
module.where("gender", "array-contains", 'female')
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            
            console.log(doc.data()["region"][0].toLowerCase(), " => ", doc.data()["gender"][0]);
    
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

Now I have multiple values of saying the same region so I wanted to like group into something like this

```
region = [female,female,female,female e.t.c]
```

or in simple terms, if a region appears more than once just create an array for that region and append gender value for that duplicate region name.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded maybe it will help someone in the future with a similar problem to mine

#Step 1
I created two variables

```
var collectionResults = [];
var groupedCollectionResults = {};
```

#Step 2
I pushed the firebase objects to the collectionResults

```
collectionResults.push(doc.data());
```

#Step 3
I then mapped collectionResults duplicates with values

```
 collectionResults.forEach(function(a) {
        groupedCollectionResults[a.region] = groupedCollectionResults[a.region] || [];
        groupedCollectionResults[a.region].push({ gender: a.gender });
    });
```

#Results

```
{
    "region": [
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "region2": [
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        },
        {
            "gender": [
                "female"
            ]
        }
    ],
   
}
```

#Conclusion
Now I can be able to count the length of the gender for a particular region, Thanks!!